# How to add minutes in date on a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have this document:

```
[
    {
        uuid: 1234,
        start: '2022-08-11T16:00:40+08:00',
        end: '2022-08-11T16:20:40+08:00'
    }
]
```

How do I get the documents that has a `start` value in between `current date` and `current date + 30 minutes`

This is my current query but it isn't working:

```
{
    start: {
        $gte: new Date(),
        $lte: {
            $dateAdd: {
                startDate: new Date(),
                unit: 'minute',
                amount: 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dateAdd` is an aggregation expression so in order to use it within the query language it must be wrapped with an `$expr`, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [
          "$start",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          "$start",
          {
            $dateAdd: {
              startDate: "$$NOW",
              unit: "minute",
              amount: 30
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5RXb4VOdIi1)